# Easy way to detect duplicated string.xml resource item in Eclipse

Tags: android

Recently, I realize Eclipse will not flag any error, if I have duplicated string.xml resource item. It allows me to run the application, or export it as signed APK.

```
<string name="demo">Demo</string>
..
..
<string name="demo">Pick Me</string>
```

For the above case, `Pick Me` will be used.

Is there any technique I can use, to detect such duplicated items before deployment? This is bit scary for delivering wrong message to customer.

Comment: Which one does it pick in this case?

Comment: You can use lint warnings to detect this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eclipse:

1. Open your project properties
2. Select Android Lint Preferences
3. Make sure the DuplicateDefinition flag is selected.

This will pop up a warning when you have the same resource defined more than once in the same resource file.

Hope this helps :)